# WCF client in a universal app

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, win-universal-app

Is it possible to call a WCF service from a universal application?

I added a service reference and the proxy was generated just fine.
But when creating a NetTcpBinding programmatically and passing that to the proxy's constructor the service model throws the exception PlatformNotSupported.

Both running the app in the simulator and on the local machine generates the same exception.

> An exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' occurred
>   in System.Private.ServiceModel.dll but was not handled in user code

"this operation is not supported"

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://test:9000/ServicesHost/PublishService");
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;

PublishingService.PublishClient proxy = new PublishingService.PublishClient(binding, address);
```

Does anybody have an example of a working WCF client in a UAP?

**EDIT**

It has something to do with the service being a duplex service!

The original contract:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IPublishCallback))]
public interface IPublish { }
```

After removing the CallbackContract attribute the UAP client can create a connection, so basic WCF works.
So I guess it's better to rephrase the question. 
Is it possible to create a **duplex** WCF client in a universal application?

**edit** servicemodel for the host

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>         
            <binding name="netTcpPublishService" openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="infinite">
                <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" enabled="true" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>  
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehaviour">      
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviour" name="PublishService.Publish">
        <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexPublishService"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="PublishService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpPublishService"
          name="netTcpPublishService" contract="PublishService.IPublish" />   
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8004/ServicesHost/PublishService" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9004/ServicesHost/PublishService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: It should be possible, I've done it in my application (albeit without passing anything to the proxy constructor, so might not be applicable).

Comment: is this in a Windows 10 UWP app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. This is how i connect in a sample app i did a while ago:

```
 using Tradeng.Srvc.Client.WinAppSimple.SrvcRefTradeng;

 private InstanceContext instanceContext;
 private TradengSrvcClientBase serviceProxy;

            instanceContext = new InstanceContext(this);
            serviceProxy = new TradengSrvcClientBase(instanceContext);

            bool result = await serviceProxy.ConnectAsync();

            if (result)
            {
              // connected...
            }
```

I used the binding from the config file that is generated when you add a reference to your service.

This is what the app looks like. Cutting edge stuff.... :O)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSg6hZn1DpE

The service itself is running as a `WebRole` on `Azure`, by the way.

Comment: If possible, please post a full stack trace. There may be some inner exception that would give a better hint about the problem.

Comment: Is that the full stack trace? Where did `PlatformNotSupportedException` go?

Comment: A few things: 1) I would expect a clean chain of exceptions leading to `PlatformNotSupportedException`, which is not what you showed. 2) You're creating your proxy manually, which is NOT necessary and, if nothing else, just makes things harder than they really need to be. All you would have to do is to go to your project and `Add Service Reference` and then add a `using` statement in your code, see my updated post. 3) When working with WCF, having service side tracing enabled is a MUST. And also use the service trace viewing tool. It shows you in excruciating details what is going on.

Comment: Regarding your edit, my service is duplex as well, so i doubt that would be the problem. How are you hosting the service? If you're hosting under IIS you have to set it up to work with `net.tcp` protocol.

Comment: My service reference generated 5 different constructors. Do you have a metadata endpoint and along with metadata exchange (mex) behavior properly set up in the config file for your service host?

Comment: Can you post the `<system.serviceModel>` section of your config file for your host project?

Comment: yes it's all there and the service is used successfully in windows forms and windows service clients. I do have another service without callbacks and that is working now also.

Comment: Ok, it pretty much looks like mine.